# JQuery function not recognizing $(this)

Tags: jquery

I have a simple jQuery function that changes the color of my table cells on click.

```
function ChangeColor( color ) {
    $(this).css('background-color', color);
}

$('td').click(function() { ChangeColor( brush_color ); } );
```

This function was unresponsive and wielded no console errors so in an effort to narrow down my problem I eliminated the brush_color / color variables however that didn't work either:

```
function ChangeColor() {
    $(this).css('background-color', '#333');
}

$('td').click(function() { ChangeColor(); } );
```

I deduced from this (and a few other tests) that my function was not recognizing `$(this)` as the `td` that had been clicked. I'm curious about what exactly is being recognized as `$(this)` in my function and why it's not wielding an error. In the mean time I passed `$(this)` as a variable and my function is now functional (see what I did there?).

Comment: Hi! A fiddle would be really useful to help solve the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Send this to function like this

```
$('td').click(function () {
    ChangeColor(brush_color, this);
});

function ChangeColor( color, ele ) {
    $(ele).css('background-color', color);
}
```

ChangeColor doesn't recognize "this" if it's not sent to the function

Answer (score 3):

There is no context for the keyword 'this' within your ChangeColor function

instead of

```
$('td').click(function() { ChangeColor(); } );
```

use

```
$('td').click(function() { ChangeColor.call(this); } );
```

This will pass a context for 'this', where the context is the clicked TD dom element